# Check whether a networkx graph is a subgraph of another one

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

I have a `networkx` graph `G`, and I wish to check whether another `networkx` graph, `H`, can be embedded in it. Simple examples include:

- checking whether `G` contains a triangle (this can be done via `networkx.triangles`)
- checking whether `G` contains a path/cycle of length `k`
- checking whether `G` contains a star with `k` leaves (this can be done via degree sequence)

etc.

I know the problem is in general *NP-complete*, but I would like to see if something a little bit better than naive exists, or if you have recommendations about how to write such a method.

Comment: why do you consider it NP-complete? As far as I understand, naive approach `is_subraph = lambda G, H: all(h_edge in G.edges() for h_edge in H.edges)` is O(m,n) which is obviously polinomial

Comment: That does not look for isomporphisms. For example, how would you check (using that method) the existence of a triangle (*any* triangle!) in a graph?

Comment: do you mean graphs are unlabeled? (not sure if it is possible to handle them with networkx)

Comment: I did not say that they are unlabelled. I just ask if `H` can be embedded into `G`, and the embedding ignores the labels. This **can** be done - it's just hard (*NP-complete*).

Comment: Sorry, stuck thinking about labeled subgraph. Since it's an NP-complete problem, are there any assumptions or special propertions on G and H? Is detection rate relaxation acceptable?

Comment: One possible assumption is that `G` is much larger (I believe that in this case it is not *NP-complete*). One other possible assumption is that `H` is of a certain class, such as a tree, a cycle, etc. However, this question is about `networkx` and not about embedding algorithms ;) I am looking for the tools that `networkx` offers, even if they are naive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been doing some extensive work with graphs in python and I'd recommend *not* using `networkx` for larger problems. Since the library is pure python it is perfect for smaller graphs and portability, but for larger subgraph isomorphisms I've found that [`graph-tool`](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/) works very well.

The function call you are looking for in graph-tool is under the topology section:

[`graph_tool.topology.subgraph_isomorphism`](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/topology.html?highlight=isomorphism#graph_tool.topology.subgraph_isomorphism)